# Can't bypass Vercel edge cache for GET request

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel, next.js13

I am using the new App Router in NextJS (13.4.6). I have a GET `/battles` endpoint. Internally, this endpoint queries the database and randomly returns 2 entities. Each time the API is called, the application expects 2 different entities.

Locally everything works fine.

When deploying to Vercel, the GET request seems to get cached, and the same 2 entities are always returned. My route logic does not get executed after the first call.

Looking at the headers, I see: `X-Vercel-Cache: HIT`. From the Vercel documentation, there are certain criteria where the cached result will be returned from Vercel Edge Network (https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/caching#cacheable-response-criteria). In particular:

- `Response does not contain the private, no-cache or no-store directives in the Cache-Control header.`

I've tried to bypass the cache by doing the following things:

- Add `'cache-control': 'private, s-maxage=0, no-store',` to my route response.
- Add `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';` to my Page component.
- Add `cache: 'no-store',` to my client fetch request.

None of these seem to be working and I'm out of ideas. A hacky fix is to change to a POST request (which solves the issue), but this is not ideal.

Comment: How does your endpoint look like? Do you use edge functions, or simple node runtime? Or do you just use SSR without an actual API endpoint?

Comment: Hi @smg! I'm facing the same issue here. What exactly did you do to solve the problem? Something more than just the accepted answer below?

Comment: @GuilhermeAvanci Yes the accepted answer worked for me. I added `export const revalidate = 0;` to my route. Note: there seems to be an open issue (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51788) for some users in the canary build regarding this functionality, so keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Route Segment Config](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#revalidate)

> The Route Segment options allows you configure the behavior of a Page,
> Layout, or Route Handler by directly exporting the following
> variables:

// copy paste did not paste in a table format
[image]

I think you need to set

```
  // default false
  export const revalidate=0 // or low number
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by exporting dynamic with force-dynamic value

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```